# IOS app with google map view isnt firing touchesEnded:withEvent: method

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, events

Im developing an IOS app which uses google maps SDK to render a map in it. I actually have a view controller, which contains another view controller that is actually the one that handles the map rendering. What i want to achieve is to do some action after the user moves the map camera and ends touching it. I saw that the best option for this particual case was to override the touchesEnded:withEvent: method. Im overriding this method inside the contained view controller but for some reason it isnt getting fired. What should be the cause of my problem?

btw mapView:idleAtCameraPosition: doesnt fit my requirements because i need the action to be executed when the user releases touching the screen (stops moving the map)

Here is some code. Its basically the same as the example provided by google maps SDK for IOS

Interface

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface MTMapViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *manager;

@end
```

Implementation

```
#import "MTMapViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/Googlemaps.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@implementation MTMapViewController {
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
    GMSMarker *marker;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:nil];
    mapView_.delegate = self;
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;
    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;
    self.manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.manager.delegate = self;
    [self.manager startUpdatingLocation];
    marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [self.manager location];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:currentLocation.coordinate
                                                               zoom:17];
    mapView_.camera = camera;
    marker.position = currentLocation.coordinate;
    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"passenger_marker.png"];
    marker.map = mapView_;
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position {
    marker.position = position.target;
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position {
    NSLog(@"mapView:idleAtCameraPosition fired");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //This wont be invoked
    NSLog(@"touchesEnded:withEvent: fired");
}

@end
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why do you have a ViewController inside a ViewController? Have you set the delegate on the mapView_? How about showing some code? =)

Comment: Hello @Brett, i've added some code as you requested, i have this approach cause i saw it was the easiest way to render the map inside a specific region of my whole screen without having to change any code of the example provided by google maps SDK for IOS (They render the map inside a UIViewController Custom class)

Comment: There are things in your code that don't make sense. E.g. you set this class as the delegate of the mapView, but this class doesn't implement GMSMapViewDelegate. That may be why you aren't seeing delegate calls, i'm not enough of an obj-c programmer to know. You should be at the very least be seeing warnings on that line.

Comment: @Brett this is my .m file (implementation), GMSMapViewDelegate protocol adoption is declared in my .h file (interface). GMSMapViewDelegate methods work well so your argument is wrong

Comment: In which case, I don't understand what you mean by "Im overriding this method inside the contained view controller but for some reason it isnt getting fired."

Comment: i refere to touchesEnded:withEvent: method (this method is not part of the GMSMapViewDelegate protocol. see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html). my requirement is to do some action after the map camera is stopped; i though that mapView:idleAtCameraPosition would do the trick, but it gets called several times until the map camera stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware idleAtCameraPosition is when map stops moving not when you lift your finger.

I had to subclass GSMapView and add PanGestureRecognizer >> State ENDED to get when finger lifted.

https://github.com/clearbrian/GoogleMapiOS_TapEndedGesture